# Changing 'save' settings of Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am currently trying to change the settings of where VS saves my project and I cannot find how to change it, I've tried looking this question up but there seem to be no question like this. Any idea where can I make this change?

Comment: "the settings of where VS saves my project" - you mean where your .sln or .csproj etc. files are created? Can't you specify that in the "Location" box when creating a new project or solution?

Answer (score 2):

Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions

Answer (score 1):

On the Tools menu, select Options.

From the Projects and Solutions folder, select General.

In the Visual Studio projects location text box, enter a location for files and projects.